# Column count doesn't match value at row 1

Tags: mysql

I want to insert data into my table but it is showing the error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am trying to insert data into my tables

Answer (score 1):

From the last image you have posted,we can find that the columns count is not the same with value count,you need to add `,` to seperate each value parameters

[image]